# Why doesn't this diode conduct in a boost converter?

Tags: diodes, boost

[image]

It seems like current should pass through the diode even in the "on state" because the current is flowing in the right direction. Is it because the current will be too low because of the closed switch "stealing" too much?

Comment: If its a boost converter, during normal functioning the voltage on the output is higher than on the input, so the diode is reverse biased. When the path through the switch is broken - (i.e. switch opened) the current from the inductor will make the voltage on the node go up (until its higher than the output), so then it conducts.

Comment: Because the capacitor will discharge into the diode but the wrong way?

Comment: Consider the voltages on both sides of the diode...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current only flows when there is a potential difference (voltage) between two nodes. Assuming this is an "ideal circuit", the switch in your schematic has zero resistance, and therefore the anode of the diode is at 0V (assuming the bottom line is the circuit "ground" reference). The cathode of the diode will either be at 0V or higher, and in either case the diode will not conduct.

Comment: Ok, but this is what I don't understand why it will be 0v

Comment: Assume the bottom line in your schematic is the reference. This is traditionally assigned a potential of 0V. Every other voltage measurement we could make on this circuit is referenced to this node. When the switch is closed, the node that used to exist between the inductor and diode anode is now short circuited to the reference node. Since we assigned 0V to the reference node, that means that the connection between the inductor and the diode anode is also 0V.

Comment: @user1140098 A perfect piece of wire and closed switch have zero volts across them. Do you understand what a short-circuit is?